# CStress graph has "Undefined" aggregate statistics for 3.6 and 3.7

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, cassandra-stress, cassandra-stress-tool

My cluster runs Cassandra 3.6 currently. When I run cassandra 3.6's cassandra-stress tool with the -graph option, the aggregates show up fine in the console output as the tool runs, but on the graph every single statistic is displayed as "Undefined" (the graphs themselves are fine). The same happens if I run cassandra 3.7's CStress tool on those nodes with the same workload. I can still run cassandra 3.5's CStress tool, and when I do that the actual statistics do show up. Is this an error on the most recent two versions of Cassandra, or is there something I need to change about the way I use the tool?

Comment: Did you fix that?